# What are the Key Server security requirements for PCI Compliance (if remote)?

Tags: key, system

I'm currently researching key management systems for PCI compliance.

The key management system is hosted with the application. The application is hosted within a PCI compliant environment.

If hosting the Key Server housing the 'Master Key' remotely, must it's environment also be PCI compliant?

I know the key management system itself must be hosted within a PCI compliant environment, but I can't find any concrete evidence one way or the other for the Key Server.

Any light on this subject would be much appreciated. I have pretty much everything nailed down at this point but want a for sure answer on whether or not the Key Server needs to be behind hardware firewall, vuln scanned, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is 'yes'. Key server is part of the key management system, and therefore should be in a PCI secured environment.

I can see how using a remote keyserver adds complications though. Ensuring that remote location is pci certified could be difficult, certainly if it's part of a 3rd party hosting environment. On the flip-side however, if done right (solid authentication, secure sockets etc) then a remote keyserver could arguably be more secure than a local one.

Really I think its worth discussing with your QSA. Unfortunately any advice given here could be nullified if your QSA disagrees.